# How to sort a series of snapshots and potential merges

Tags: git, sorting, commit, heuristics

I'm converting a project to git. We have lots of code snaphots as zip files, with an approximate date order, and 'version' info. but it's not as reliable as it could be, and there was some branching and merging as well (manual merge using BC2).

I've separated out most of the snapshots by major revision number and date, and have a pretty, and linear, commit sequence.

I'm trying to see if using the `diff`s would show which commits are out of sequence or are possible merge candidates - the comparison scope is about -4/+1 commit, over sequences that might be 60 commits long.

Does anyone have any suggestions as to possible metrics for checking the "out-of-sequenceness" of such a constructed history. My *nix script skill are low, not having used it in anger for almost 30 years;-). I'm thinking of number of files affected, and number of lines changed/in common, or something like that. Has anyone any experience of this?

Answer (score 1):

One possible metric that may be of interest would be comparing commits against both their parent and grandparent - if you see a higher similarity (= smaller diffstat) against the grandparent, it suggests there may be an out-of-sequence commit or revert.

Comment: I may use the `--numstat` option as then I can process the results with Excel! Its now a case of reading up on *nix scripting to get that data...